# using 18n and I18n:Alchemy in rails in order to translate a text value according to the locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application, there is a field credit_debit that has two string values: 'credit' and 'debit'.
These two terms should be shown in a localized form to the user, so that when the app is using an italian locale they should be translated into 'avere' and 'dare'.
I could write my own setter/getter method for the credit_debit field and handle this issue inside it, but maybe I could leverage the I18n architecture to do so in a way that is consistent with the rest of the localization. If it's possible, how can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Can't see the problem if you're already using i18n localization.
Just use the field as a key for i18n (with a prefix if you like)

```
t("prefix_#{credit_debit}")
```

and just define the strings for both your locales.
So in your en locale:

```
prefix_credit: credit
prefix_debit: debit
```

And in your it locale:

```
prefix_credit: avere
prefix_debit: dare
```